# Every element being created twice in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am populating a core data from a CSV file like this:

```
name;description;city
abc;bla bla bla;Los Angeles
def;blub blub blub;New York
ghi;clap clap clap;San Francisco
```

Then I have this code to populate the database

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
    
class CreateDatabase {
  
  class func createIn(context:NSManagedObjectContext) {
    var csv = readCSV("elements")!
    csv.removeFirst()
    
    for oneItem in csv {
      if oneItem.first!.count == 0 { continue }
      
      let newItem:MyElement = MyElement(context: context)
      newItem.name = oneItem[0]
      newItem.description = oneItem[1]
      newItem.city = oneItem[2]
      
      do {
       try context.save()
      }
      catch let error{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }

    }
  }
  
  
  
  
  class func readCSV(_ fileName:String) -> [[String]]? {
    if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "csv") {
      do {
        let data = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
        
        var result: [[String]] = []
        let rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        for row in rows {
          let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ";")
          result.append(columns)
        }
        return result
      } catch {
        // contents could not be loaded
        return nil
      }
    } else {
      return nil
    }
    
  }
```

and I call this from `MyApp.swift`.

```
init() {
    if (CREATE_DB) {
      CreateDatabase.createIn(context: PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
      exit(0)
    }
  }
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
```

Every single entry is created twice.

I have verified a thousand times and the line

```
CreateDatabase.createIn(context: PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
```

is just called one time.

Any ideas why every single entry is created twice?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Every single entry is created twice.

Comment: Did you step through the code in `createIn(context:NSManagedObjectContext)` and see what happens? Did you print the result of `readCSV`?

Comment: yes, every line is only executed once but at the end, the final `.sqlite` file contains a duplicate of everything.

Comment: Did you check if the `.sqlite` file is empty before adding new items? Also, try moving `context.save()` outside of the for-loop. No need to execute it after every insertion.

Comment: yes, there is no sqlite on disk when the process starts. I tried to move the save outside the loop. No difference.

Comment: So how do you know each item is created twice?

Comment: I open the sqlite and see there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225330/discussion-between-koen-and-duck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending two days trying to solve this, I cannot just conclude that this is some kind of bug.

My solution was to check if an entry was already created before creating a new one, even knowing the creation line was just being issued once.

I have used a code like this

```
class func createNewItem(term:String, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Expressao {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: String(describing: Self.self))
    request.returnsDistinctResults = true
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = true
    
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "term == %@", term)
    
    do {
      let result = try contexto.fetch(request) as! [MyElement]
      if result.count == 0 {
        return MyElement(context: context)
      } else {
        return result.first!
      }
    } catch {
      return MyElement(context: context)
    }
  }
```

It is now generating the correct database. No duplicates.